# HiveContext - unable to access hbase table mapped in hive as external table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, hivecontext, spark-submit

I am trying to access the hbase table mapped in hive using HiveContext in Spark. But I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` Exceptions..  Below is my code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.sql("select * from dbn.hvehbasetable")
```

I am getting the below error..

> 17/06/22 07:17:30 ERROR log: error in initSerDe:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe not found
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe not found
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2120)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:385)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:276)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:258)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:605)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1$$anonfun$3.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:342)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1$$anonfun$3.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:337)
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:337)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:332)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:290)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:237)

Can anyone help which class I need to import to read the hbase tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, you need add `hive-hbase-handler` jar in classpath/ auxpath if you haven't done that already.

Get your version from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-hbase-handler).

Let me know if this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Can you explain which classpath? Hbase classpath?

Comment: spark classpath